# pip: no module named _internal

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem when I try to use pip in any way. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4

I should say that I've used it already, and I never had any problem, but starting today when I use any command I always get the same error (as an example using `pip --upgrade`).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal
```

I have tried doing `sudo apt-get remove python-pip` followed by `sudo apt-get install python-pip` but nothing changed.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you attempt to upgrade or install a newer pip?  `/usr/local/bin/pip` is not where `python-pip` or `python3-pip` install the command for system wide use...

Comment: Did you upgrade to pip 10? I think this is related to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem. At first I noticed that there is no problem if i call `python -m pip`. Then i removed a file named pip under `/usr/local/bin` (I don't know why it was there), now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 7):

I Ran:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade pip
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu packaged version of `pip` can be pretty old, which can lead to this issue if you end up with simultaneous installations of both `pip<=9` (from Ubuntu, in `/usr/bin`) and `pip>=10` (installed manually, in `~/.local` or `/usr/local/bin`). One simple way to avoid this issue altogether is not to install `pip` system-wide at all, but only within each Python virtual environment:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install --upgrade pip
```